# Is there a CSS only way to rotate 90 deg in responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I have a (nice?) responsive design of a table (done with flex) - if the display is wide enough it looks like this (labels 'c' and 'd' rotated -90):

```
|aaaaaaa|bbbbbbb|c   |d   |
|       |       |c   |d   |
|       |       |c   |d   |
+-------+-------+----+----+
|   1111|   2222|3   |4   | 
+-------+-------+----+----+
|   xxxx|   yyyy|z   |?   |
```

if it gets (to) small it changes to:

```
|aaaaaaa|bbbbbbb|
|c      |d      |
|c      |d      |
|c      |d      |
+-------+-------+
|   1111|   2222|
|3      |4      |   
+-------+-------+
|   xxxx|   yyyy|
|z      |?      |
```

so far so fine, and working, and was a playing around with transform and padding.

*EDIT: the trick was to make all rotated labels the same height and width;*

Lets say - now I have to put a background to the labels - the problem is, that the rotated divs for c&d have a fixed height and width that fits to my logic.

*EDIT: the problem is that translated text do not fit in any more;*

But they should have:

```
width: 100%parent_height;
height: 100%parent_width;
```

not to talk about `top` and `left`

My jQuery solution looks like this (just trans H and W):

```
rotate90=()->
    $('.rotate90').each (i,e) =>
        $e=$(e)
        $e.css(width: '100%', height: '100%')
        [w,h]=[$e.outerWidth(),$e.outerHeight()]
        $e.outerWidth(h).outerHeight(w)
        .css(top: (h-w)/2, left: (w-h)/2)
```

and call it when needed

```
$(window).load( =>
    rotate90()
    $(window).on('resize.rotate90', rotate90)   
)
```

css behind is just simple

```
.rotate90 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: left;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**But** is there a way to to that w/o scripting?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/95qur86t/1/)
[Fiddle 2 with different width and long text](https://jsfiddle.net/95qur86t/4/)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @Juanín: yes, but will take a bit, I am not allowed to cut'n'paste true code here ...

Comment: create a fiddle

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     .rotate90 {
       transform: rotate(-90deg);
       text-align: left;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       position: absolute;
}
```

Google different @media screen varients and find the ones you would like to use based off your devices screen size.

You don't need a script to create the rotation

You might also want to add a transition time to your css so it is more smooth

```
.rotate90{
transition: 2s;
 -webkit-transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: the rotation is not dependent of view - width, that was not the question